# Laravel Store Value if Checkbox is Checked

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-5.6

I am storing multiple values in Laravel. In the form, I have check box for each input and I want to store value if checkbox is checked for that input. The problem I am facing is no matter which checkbox I check, its always **saving from first input value**. If I check one option, it is storing first value. If I check 2 options, it is storing first and second values, and so on.

Here is the form for checkbox

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checked[]" value="{{ $employee->id }}">
```

The store method

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        foreach ($request->employee_id as $key => $val) {
            $payrolls = new Payroll;
            if (isset($request->checked[$key])) {
                $payrolls->basic = $request->basic[$key];
                $payrolls->employee_id = $val;
                $payrolls->save();
            }
        }

        return redirect('/');
    }
```

Comment: are you sure that the first value checked is false?

Comment: Yes, I have checked multiple times.

Comment: any JS involved?

Comment: not yet. I am preferring a php only solution

Comment: Use `isset($request->get('checked')[$key])`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method isset checking by the key, but in the array of checked you need to search by the value, use method in_array()

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    foreach ($request->employee_id as $key => $val) {
        $payrolls = new Payroll;
        if (in_array($val, $request->checked)) {
            $payrolls->basic = $request->basic[$key];
            $payrolls->employee_id = $val;
            $payrolls->save();
        }
    }

    return redirect('/');
}
```

Comment: Getting error `in_array() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given`